# How to upgrade from Virtuoso 6.1 to 7.x?

Tags: ubuntu, virtuoso

I want to know if it is possible to upgrade from Virtuoso 6.1 to 7.x without loosing my database ?
Configuration: Ubuntu 18
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In this, as in so many things, [the documentation](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/UpgradingToVOS610), especially [on **Upgrading from Release 6.x to Release 7.x**](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/UpgradingToVOS610#Upgrading%20from%20Release%206.x%20to%20Release%207.x), is your friend.